# How to extract a sub-array in numpy efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I have an image given as a 3D numpy array (width, height and color as dimensions). Now I would like to extract all possible sub-images of a given shape. For example, the width and height of the original image is 300 and 200 pixels, respectively, and I would like to extract all sub-images with width and heights equal to 10 and 20 pixels, respectively. Moreover, each sub-image I would like to have as 1D array (for that I need to specify a particular ordering of pixels).

I solve the problem in the following way:

```
for col0 in range(w_max - max_shift):
    x3s_new = [x + col0 for x in x3s]
    for row0 in range(h_max - max_shift):

        vec_1 = []
        for col_shift, row_shift in px_inds:
            col = col0 + col_shift
            row = row0 + row_shift
            vec_1 += [ia[row, col, 0], ia[row, col, 1], ia[row, col, 2]]

        y3s_new = [y + row0 for y in y3s]
        vec_2 = list(ia[y3s_new, x3s_new, z3s])
```

In the above code I make a loop over columns and rows of the "matrix" representing the image. Then each pixel (given by its column and row) I treat as the left-top corner of the sub-image and extract the sub-image.

The `vec_1` and `vec_2` are the desired sub-images given as 1D arrays (lists). They are identical, I just wanted to test what way is faster. Surprisingly, it take more time to generate `vec_2` than `vec_1`. However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182076/how-to-extract-a-list-of-elements-given-by-their-indices-from-a-numpy-array-effi) to my question it was expected to be faster. So, why it is not faster?

Finally, I also would like to know if there is a faster alternative to looping over all columns and rows of the image-matrix.

To summarize, my question is: How to achive what I need in faster way? At the moment it takes me about 5 minutes to "process" one image and it is not acceptable for my purposes.

Comment: Do you know about slicing?

Comment: @cfh, no (some_symbols_to_make_it_acceptably_long).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Numpy slicing.

Given a 3D numpy array `M`, you can select an sub-array of it, with for instance,

```
M_selection = M[i_min:i_max, j_min:j_max, k_min:k_max]
```

or alternatively, explicitly defining the slice,

```
sl_i = slice(i_min, i_max)
sl_j = slice(j_min, j_max)
sl_k = slice(k_min, k_max)
M_selection = M[sl_i, sl_j, sl_k]
```

where `(i_min, i_max)`, etc. are the boundaries of the sub-array.

See the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) of advanced Numpy indexing for more details.